# Starting another activity in onCreate of mainActivity generates error

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am building a simple app that (at every startup) gets preferences and checks if user agreed with terms. If not it starts another activity with terms. Here is my code to start activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean termsConfirmed = preferences.getBoolean("termsConfirmed", false);
        if(!termsConfirmed) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, confirmTerms.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TERMS_CONFIRMATION);
        }
}
```

However this causes nullpointerexception in this method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        listener.refresh = refresh;
}
```

This is full logcat error code:

```
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at hzs.sk.hzs.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:141)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2158)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1056)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1259)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:80)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:119)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-03 09:15:20.577: E/AndroidRuntime(1996):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I start activity whithout result so like `startActivity()` and finish it by calling `finish()` then it works but I need a result of that activity so I must start is as I do. Any ideas?

Thanks in forward

Comment: Can you paste your LogCat error code?

Comment: done, I thought that if I start another activity my main activity wont get to this point until started activitiy is finished but it is obviously not working like that

Comment: Try to add `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);` on `onCreateOptionsMenu` or just `return true`

Comment: sorry I didnt copy whole code but I have return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) at the end of onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what causes exception.But if you need result of second Activity,you can save the result as value of static field of another class(also static field of first Activity) and after finishing first Activity and resuming first Activity,use value of that field.

Comment: great idea, but it is better for me to do it by startacitivtyforresult

Comment: @horin OK! Let me know the result.

Comment: after trying a few combinations of code I learnt that using startactivityforresult is only possible option for me. If I call it after problematic code it works but it shows my firstactivity and then switches to second and I wanted to avoid this behaviour

Comment: @horin Why you did not use an Activity to display `splash screen` and there decide which Activity must be shown?

Comment: I have solved it by using start splashscreen as you suggested and it is working as I wanted... thank you